# Continue ordered list numbering automatically

Tags: html, list

I wonder how I can have the following ordered list in html

```
1 Item 1
1A Item 2
1B Item 3
2 Item 4
2A Item 5
2B Item 6
2C Item 7
3 Item 8
```

Comment: What you show is not an ordered list.  Show the code you have, and you will have a better chance of getting a helpful answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```css
ol.number, .letter > ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}  

ol.number {
  counter-reset: number;
}

.letter > ol {
  counter-reset: letter;
}

ol.number > li:not(.letter):before {
  content: counter(number, decimal) " ";
  counter-increment: number;
}

.letter > ol > li:before {
  content: counter(number, decimal) counter(letter, upper-alpha) " ";
  counter-increment: letter;
}
```

```html
<ol class="number">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li class="letter">
    <ol>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li class="letter">
    <ol>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item 8</li>
</ol>
```

Or if you'd prefer to automate counting the index as well:

```css
ol.number, .letter > ol {
  list-style-type: none;
}  

ol.number {
  counter-reset: number index;
}

.letter > ol {
  counter-reset: letter;
}

ol.number > li:not(.letter):before {
  content: counter(number, decimal) " ";
  counter-increment: number;
}

.letter > ol > li:before {
  content: counter(number, decimal) counter(letter, upper-alpha) " ";
  counter-increment: letter;
}

ol.number li:not(.letter):after {
  content: " " counter(index, decimal);
  counter-increment: index;
}
```

```html
<ol class="number">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="letter">
    <ol>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li class="letter">
    <ol>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: @Andrea I'd prefer to use the CSS2 syntax for backwards compatibility. Next time please leave that in a comment.

Comment: Aren't nested `<ol>`'s supposed to be within an `<li>` element?

Comment: @MichaelTranchida it's a semantic preference, but it's not necessary, no.