# R Markdown Presentation: How to continue a numbered list across a slide?

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

Let's say I want to create this numbered list:

1. *Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...*
2. *Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit...*
3. *Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia...*
4. *Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate...*

In R Markdown, the documentation suggests that to continue such a list after an interruption, one should prepend each list item with `(@)` as follows:

```
(@) Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...
(@) Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit...

 This is an interrupting block of text...

(@) Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia..
(@) Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate...
```

and this will continue the numbering after the interruption.

However, I tried, without success, to use this approach in continuing a numbered list in an **ioslides presentation** generated from R Markdown i.e.

```
(@) Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit...

 ***

(@) Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia..
```

where `***` represents the slide break.

Is there a way I can achieve number continuation across the slide break?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the HTML `<ol>` tag (`ol` is for ordered list) which has an optional `start` argument.

Here is minimal example:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: ioslides_presentation
---

## Slide

<ol>
<li> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error...
<li> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit...
</ol>

This is an interrupting block of text...

<ol start=3>
<li> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia..
<li> Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate...
</ol>
```

[image]

This also works across slides.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. But more importantly, I learnt something I never knew - that I could use HTML tags right inside R Markdown. This new knowledge will make a HUGE difference going forward. Cheers!

Comment: Note that with a bit more html (e.g., in a .css), you can set up styles to [continue the numbering automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927354/continue-ordered-list-numbering-automatically)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works ok if you only have a few items, but if you are dealing with many listed items and the number may change (i.e. you add or subtract some), the `<ol start=3>` approach becomes tedious.

Additionally, the link in the comment of the accepted answer ([Continue ordered list numbering automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927354/continue-ordered-list-numbering-automatically)) did not work across slides for me using xaringan.

As a workaround, you can create a counter using embedded R code so that you don't have to manually reference the item number. I tested this with xaringan but not ioslides.

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "with xaringan"
author: "Yihui Xie"
date: "2016/12/12"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

## Slide

<ol>
<li> Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error... `r q<-1`
<li> Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit... `r q<-q+1`
</ol>

This is an interrupting block of text...

---

And a new slide....

<ol start=`q+1`>
<li> Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia.. `r q<-q+1`
<li> Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate...`r q<-q+1`
</ol>
```

The `r q<-q+1` blocks are not necessary in the last few items. If I'm going to be doing this a lot, I simply store the `ol` tag and the increment block into a register in Emacs so they can be called upon quickly.

Comment: I will definitely look at this. I'm not sure xaringan existed at the time though.